# ZEND htaccess php_value for special files

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Basically I'm not allowed to use PHP's `ini_set` function to increase upload file size for a formular.

Now I'm trying to change it via htaccess, which works but seems to have the effect that its increased in every controller/form/view.

How am I able to increase the `post_max_size` in only one special controller/form/view?
When I put the htaccess in the public folder where the index.php from ZEND is, it works, but then it works in every form/controller.

I was trying it with (`food` is my controller), but this wont work:

```
<FilesMatch "^(food)">
    php_value post_max_size 200MB
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that in your main `.htaccess` file. Put the php vars in an `.htaccess` file in the **same** folder as the upload script.

```
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
```

Note: You might need to include the max filesize too because both are needed to increase upload limit.

Comment: but which one is the "right" folder?
Zend builds the view live. That means a controller and a model fills a view (all in different folders).